# Is it possible to use read() method of an opencv VideoCapture object from parent process?

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing

I would like to create a VideoCapture object in my parent process and call VideoCapture.read() in a child process as below:

```
from multiprocessing import Process


def foo(cap):
    print(cap)
    print(cap.read()[0])

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print(cap)
print(cap.read()[0])
p = Process(target=foo, args=(cap,))
p.start()
```

However, the output would be:

```
<VideoCapture 0x11b1d4f90>
True
<VideoCapture 0x11b1d4f90>
False
```

While I expect the output to be:

```
<VideoCapture 0x11b1d4f90>
True
<VideoCapture 0x11b1d4f90>
True
```

Any advices would much appreciated!

Comment: where is your `see_frame` method? and in code  `foo` method is not called anywhere.

Comment: @ManaliKagathara it was my mistake. now the code is corrected

Comment: specify your problem in depth. your problem related to sharing an object between process or about cv2 modules.

Comment: @ManaliKagathara I think the problem is specific for sharing an opencv VideoCapture object